# order type: $\omega$ , $\eta$ and $\lambda$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is from "Theory of Sets" by E.Kamke .This is about the order type: $\omega$ , $\eta$ and $\lambda$.

The order types $\omega$ , $\eta$ and $\lambda$ are defined like this in the book:

> The order type of the set of natural numbers , ordered according to increasing magnitude , is denoted by $\omega$. It is customary to denote by $\lambda$ the order type of the set of all real numbers ordered according to increasing magnitude , and by  $\eta$ , the set of all rational numbers ordered in analogous fashion.

So I have some questions about these order types:

1. Why these order types are different/distinct from each other.
2. There is a nice visualization of the order type $\omega$ in wikipedia.

[image]

Is there a nice visualization for the order type $\eta$ and $\lambda$ as well ?

Comment: There's a great one for $\lambda$: __________________________________________________________

Comment: As for question 1.: Try to argue that there exists an order isomorphism between these spaces, and see if you can find a contradiction. As a hint, $\omega$ has no infinite decreasing sequence, and $\lambda$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more complete answer to (1) than Vstovep:

- $\omega$ is well-ordered: every non-empty subset of it has a least element. Since $\omega$ does not have a maximum element, this also implies that every element has an immediate successor, with no other element between them. $\lambda$ and $\eta$ are not well-ordered. They each have many subsets without a least element, and between any two elements there is another element,
- $\lambda$ has the supremum property: Any subset which is bounded above has a least upper bound (which may or may not be in the subset itself). $\omega$ also has the supremum property, but $\eta$ does not. For example, the set of all rational numbers whose squares are $< 2$ does not have a least upper bound. And as Vsotvep points out, $\lambda$ cannot be put in bijection with the natural numbers, while $\omega$ and $\eta$ can.
- $\eta$ is neither well-ordered nor satisfies the supremum property, but can be put in bijection with the natural numbers.